# Colimits in the idempotent completion (Proof of Theorem 5.5.1.1, HTT)

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, infinity-categories

The following fact seems to be implicitly used in the proof of (4)$\implies$(5) of Theorem 5.5.1.1 of Lurie's *Higher Tops Theory*:

> Let $\kappa$ be a small regular cardinal, and let $\mathcal{C}$ be a small $\infty$-category with $\kappa$-small colimits. Then the idempotent completion of $\mathcal{C}$ has $\kappa$-small colimits.

It is not clear to me why this is true. (Or perhaps I am misreading the proof.) Can anyone offer me a help? Thanks in advance.

---

Let me leave a comment which might be relevant. According to Lemma 5.4.2.4, the idempotent completion of $\mathcal{C}$ is equivalent to the full subcategory of $\operatorname{Ind}_{\kappa}(\mathcal{C})$ spanned by the $\kappa$-compact objects. So the above claim follows if we can show that $\operatorname{Ind}_{\kappa}(\mathcal{C})$ has $\kappa$-small colimits. This will *follow* from Theorem 5.5.1.1, but that would be circular.

Comment: Isn't $C$ already idempotent complete by hypothesis?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Yes, if $\kappa >\omega$. But if $\kappa=\omega$, then idempotent completeness doesn't follow from finite cocompleteness since the indexing category for idempotents is not finite. (A relevant discussion can be found at the beginning of section 4.4.5 of HTT.)

Comment: One can prove more directly that $\mathrm{Ind}(\mathcal C)$ has small colimits if $\mathcal C$ has finite colimits, by showing that pushouts can be computed "levelwise" (using Prop. 5.3.5.15).

Comment: Since we're already reduced to caring about $\kappa = \omega$, then we need to show that the idempotent completion $\hat{\mathcal{C}}$ of $\mathcal{C}$ has pushouts and an initial object. It's straightforward to argue that the initial object of $\hat{\mathcal{C}}$ is just the initial object of $\mathcal{C}$.

Comment: For pushouts, you can argue that a span in $\hat{\mathcal{C}}$ is a retract of span in $\mathcal{C}$ (which can then be extended to a colimit diagram). It suffices to extend the original span to a square which is a retract of this second (pushout), as it is then also automatically a colimit diagram.

Comment: As an alternative to this last step, use @MarcHoyois's approach to argue that $\mathsf{Ind}(\hat{\mathcal{C}})$ has all pushouts (it's equivalent to $\mathsf{Ind}(\mathcal{C})$) and then use this to automatically extend the span in such a way that it's a retract of the pushout from $\mathcal{C}$.

Comment: @MarcHoyois Thanks! You saved my day. Would you mind turning your comment into an answer? I will gladly accept it.

Comment: @DanielGratzer Thank you for your comment. I like your direct argument.